# What does "Most Japanese cars open sideways" mean?

Tags: locks, door

When I read a comic book called "Thief of Thieves" by Robert Kirkman, I encountered this conversation between the thief (Redmond) and his apprentice (Celia). Seeing Celia struggling with opening a locked car door with a coat hanger, Redmond starts lecturing how to steal a car.

Redmond: Now, if you're really committed to sticking with the classic coat hanger here, you do need to buy American. ***Most Japanese cars open sideways.*** From there, you need a screwdriver to get some room to play with, and...then you just need to apply some zen to it. There we go. Car in three steps.
Celia: Oh my god, that is amazing! Nobody on youtube could do it that fast.

What I do not understand here is why Redmond recommends Celia to target American cars instead of Japanese ones. Most American cars also open sideways, right? Or, is there any difference between American and Japanese cars in terms of the door lock mechanism?

I'm not a native speaker of English, so I may be misunderstanding something in this conversation. Your kind help is much appreciated.

Comment: VTC because any comprehensive answer will include details on how to break into a car successfully

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about a comic book, not an actual problem related to vehicle maintenance & repair.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is from a comic, the answer varies in accuracy depending on the authors accuracy to reality and time period it's set in.

On thought is the "plunger" style lock vs a flip style or slide style. The "plunger" has a metal or plastic peg that moves up and down vertically to lock or unlock. The flip and slide style locks have a horizontal action rather than vertical.

No I believe that it's accurate to say that it doesn't matter where the car was made - it can have either. I've seen plenty of plunger style lock on American and Euro cars as well as Japanese. I've also seen plenty of flip or slide style locks on American and Euro cars... so I don't think that one is necessarily more common than the other with current production vehicles.

I will say that just about every older (pre-90's) American vehicle I've had or worked on did have plunger style locks... but there were a few that had slide locks.

Anyway... hope that helps.

Comment: I personally, would not rely on comics to provide information that I would use to work on my car or apply to any real situation... But if it floats your boat, that's your choice.

Comment: @SolarMike I totally agree.

Comment: Thank you so much, kyle_engineer! Sorry for asking an off topic question. I will be more careful next time.